# Is there a way to recognize text in a graphic or a picture with tesseract?

Tags: tesseract

First, sorry for my English. I have a question regarding tesseract. Is there a way to recognize text in a graphic or a picture without having to clean the image you want to recognize? in what I read there to clean the image first, remove graphics and photographs and leave only the text. But I want the user to upload to the server and newspaper clippings you can recognize this news without human intervention. It can be tricky. But if you know any other way I could do as they are grateful. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't.

Tesseract is made for reading text and only text. When you perform OCR on a subject with both text and an image, Tesseract spits out things it finds in the image (garbled crap).

You *can* detect image regions and crop them out, though. I think that would be a better question to ask.

Comment: Hi Blender, thank you so much. it's very important to now that. (i' did not). The question that you suggest, are you now that??? 
PDT: sorry for my english

Comment: It's not very simple to do, and I'm not sure what to answer, as I've never done that. Maybe you could ask another question through the `Ask Question` button? More people would see it.

Comment: Excellent Blender!!! Thank you so much. I do it like you said. Greetings from Colombia.